# Is there a minhag to start blowing the shofar from the first day of Rosh Chodesh Elul?

Tags: tefilla, rosh-chodesh-new-month, shofar

I went to a shul this morning that blew the shofar, as far as I had known it was always blown starting the second day of Rosh Chodesh, for clarity I daven nusach Sefard and both places were a nusach sefard minyan.

Comment: Like is stated in HaYom Yom, there was a practice by the Lubavitcher Rebbe to spend the first day of Rosh Chodesh Elul "practicing" with the shofar in preparation to actually start blowing shofar starting on the first day of Elul (meaning the second day of Rosh Chodesh Elul).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mishna Berurah 581:3, there are some who have the custom to do it the first day, and some the second day.

מר"ח ואילך וכו' - יש מתחילין מיום ראשון דר"ח ויש מתחילין מיום שני דר"ח וכ"כ בסי' דה"ח.

Answer (score 1):

In Stolin-Karlin the minhag is to blow on the first day. We also have the minhag to blow the full תשר"ק תש"ק תר"ק every day.

Comment: Chabad also does the full set.